# Как хранить список разных объектов, наследуемых от одного и того же объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю стратегию на unity. Есть игровое поле, состоящее из клеток. Есть класс Cell, от него наследуется Building, от него Collector, Container, House и тд. Допустим, я получил определенную Cell по ее координатам, но как узнать, House это, Collector или Container, чтобы взять из нее соответствующую информацию? Думал о проверке тега и получении соответствующего компонента, но как то не совсем красиво что ли. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать.

Comment: `if (obj is House) House houseObj = (House)obj;`

Comment: @Yaroslav вроде еще так можно в C# `if (obj is House houseObj) { ... }`